# Parsing a string with a number on basis of culture

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I am working on an application which extracts numbers from strings based on different cultures. 
Here's my method:

```
    private decimal ParseCurrencyAmount(string fieldValue, string clientCulture)
    {
        decimal decimalValue;
        if (decimal.TryParse(fieldValue, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(clientCulture), out decimalValue))
        {
            return decimalValue;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

the string 40'000 is 40,000 in swiss french culture however I am not able to parse the same.
Is there any other culture which can parse this string correctly?

Input:
fieldValue : "40'000" (forty thousand)
clientCulture : fr-CH not working but I can change the culture.
TIA

Comment: `40,000` is fourty with decimal zeros or forty thousand?

Comment: it is forty thousand

Comment: `decimal.TryParse("40'000", NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-CH"), out decimalValue` returns `true`. What is your question exactly? Why do you wanna parse it as `Currency` by the way?

Comment: Okay, I found the problem, I want it to parse as a currency, but the problem is the string is "40’000" and not "40'000". spot the diferrence in apostrophe. it is a closing/opening apostrophe diferrence

40'000 is being parsed correctly